# How do I execute a script on another server using FTP in UNIX? How to pass variable on it?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix, ftp

Consider I have two servers A and B.
And on the server B, I have a script `test.sh`.

I want to execute this `test.sh` from server A using FTP connection between them and also I want to pass a variable to the script of B but the variable is defined at A.

OR

If I SSH to server B from A,
just after ssh command  , i will execute the shell script at B.
But if i want to add a variable (that i have defined while i was at A)
as an argument to script of B. how would i do it ? any suggestion ?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*Some*, but not many, FTP servers support `SITE EXEC command`.

In the common *nix `ftp` client, you can use `quote` command to execute the `SITE` FTP command:

```
quote SITE EXEC test.sh param1 param2
```

But this will probably not work with your server. In most cases, you won't be able to execute a shell command over FTP.

Though if you have an SSH/shell access, use the `ssh` to execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code is difficult to see what you are trying to do exactly, but if you use double quotes your variable should be interpolated before send the value of it to the remote host, ex:

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 "~/bin/script.sh $Local_Variable"
```

Comment: just after ssh there is some welcome message and banners that comes on server B and because of which the command associated with ssh execute before the terminal of machine B comes.
any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Could you send what you are trying to do and the response you are getting?