# How to run Python script in FTP server using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, ftp, ftplib

I want to run Python script located on server using another Python script with FTP.

Below is my (`hello.py`) file location I want to run.

[image]

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('host')
ftp.login(user='user', passwd = 'password')

print("successfully connected")
print ("File List:")
files = ftp.dir()
print (files)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run anything on an FTP server, no matter how.
See a similar question: [Run a script via FTP connection from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50489730/850848)
It's about PowerShell, not Python, but it does not matter.

---

You will have to have another access. Like an SSH shell access.

---

If you actually want to download the script from the FTP server and run it on the local machine use:

```
with open('hello.py', 'wb') as f
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR hello.py', f.write)
system('python hello.py')
```

---

If you do not want to store the script to a local file, this might work too:

```
r = StringIO()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR hello.py', r.write)
exec(r.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a system() call:

```
system('python hello.py')
```

Note: use the full path to the hello.py script.

An alternative is to use the subprocess module.

Comment: I do not think that this is what OP asks for.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the runpy module

```
import runpy

runpy.run_path("code.py")
```

Refer to the documentation page for more details [runpy module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html)

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hello.py'

Comment: hello.py is located on server, not on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner (no modules required!):

```
exec(open('hello.py','r').read())
```

Comment: this line will search file in program directory on local machine, "hello.py" is located on ftp server.

Comment: @MahipalSingh I see.